# kaniko docker build: can't find command

Tags: docker, kaniko

Newbie to [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko), and try to build docker images in ubuntu docker host.

I have a local `Dockerfile` and `main.go` app

```
# Dockefile
FROM golang:1.10.3-alpine AS build
ADD . /src
RUN cd /src && go build -o app

FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /src/app /app/
CMD [ "./app" ]
```

```
#main.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
}
```

And in command line, i run

```
docker run -it  -v $(pwd):/usr \
   gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest \
   --dockerfile=Dockerfile --context=/usr --no-push
```

Unfortunately, I got error like below

```
...
INFO[0006] Skipping paths under /proc, as it is a whitelisted directory
INFO[0006] Using files from context: [/usr]
INFO[0006] ADD . /src
INFO[0006] Taking snapshot of files...
INFO[0006] RUN cd /src && go build -o app
INFO[0006] cmd: /bin/sh
INFO[0006] args: [-c cd /src && go build -o app]
/bin/sh: go: not found
error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 127
```

What's wrong? (docker version 18.09.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use different path for context in kaniko. Your command to run this build should look like this:

```
docker run -it  -v $(pwd):/context \
   gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest \
   --dockerfile=Dockerfile --context=/context --no-push
```

In your command with `/usr` as context kaniko where overriding this path in all of Dockerfiles and in golang image, `go` is located in `/usr` path thats why it couldn't find it then

```
# which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```